# weblogic.management.provider.EditWaitTimedOutException

Tags: jenkins, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am currently using Jenkins 2.138.1, Oracle Weblogic 12c.

I tried to deploy the war file into Weblogic server by using Jenkins Weblogic Deployer Plugin.

The Jenkins Build will be triggered every midnight 3am.

Sometimes the build is success, but sometimes failed with the error below:

```
Deployment Plan: null
App root: null
App config: null
Deployment Options: {
isRetireGracefully=true,
isGracefulProductionToAdmin=false,
isGracefulIgnoreSessions=false,
rmiGracePeriod=-1,
retireTimeoutSecs=-1,
undeployAllVersions=false,
archiveVersion=null,
planVersion=null,
isLibrary=false,
libSpecVersion=null,
libImplVersion=null,
stageMode=null,
clusterTimeout=3600000,
altDD=null,
altWlsDD=null,
name=myapp,
securityModel=null,
securityValidationEnabled=false,
versionIdentifier=null,
isTestMode=false,
forceUndeployTimeout=0,
defaultSubmoduleTargets=true,
timeout=0,
deploymentPrincipalName=null,
useExpiredLock=false
}

[BasicOperation.execute():445] : Initiating undeploy operation for app, 
myApp, on targets: [BasicOperation.execute():447] : MyMgdSvr1
weblogic.management.provider.EditWaitTimedOutException: Waited 0 
milliseconds at weblogic.utils.StackTraceDisabled.unknownMethod()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found the solution, the issue is actually caused by it cannot obtain the edit lock from Weblogic admin server.

Therefore before I un-deploy and deploy the application, I overwritten the user lock so that my instance is able to obtain the lock.

Comment: I am having the same issues as you had (EditWaitTimedOutException when trying to acquire lock before undeploy/deploy) when you asked this. Can you provide the implemented solution/changes? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Repoker I have a Python script which call the following functions.
edit()
cancelEdit('Y')
disconnect()